# Android onNewIntent is not being called

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent, oauth, chrome-custom-tabs

I am working on `Android/Kotlin` with Google `Chrome Custom Tab`, CCT for doing an `oAuth` for 3rd party server. When oAuth is completed, `CCT` is supposed to redirects to my `redirect_url` where, I am catching it in `onNewIntent` and `onCreate`. Unfortunately my `redirect_url` is not being called for the first launch. But it gets called when I relaunch it for second time. What can be the possible cause?

### My AndroidManifests.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="test"
                android:host="apps.test.abc.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

### My MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Logger.v(classTag, "onNewIntent")
    }

    override fun onCreate(onCreate: Bundle?)
        super.onCreate(onCreate)
        Logger.v(classTag, "onCreate")
    }
}
```

### My call to CCT

```
val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
val cctIntent = builder.build()
cctIntent.intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
cctIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
cctIntent.launchUrl(mContext, Uri.parse(3RD_PARTY_OAUTH_URL))
```

When I launch 3RD_PARTY_OAUTH_URL with CCT for the 1st time after oAuth is complete it does not call to `test://apps.test.abc.com`, But when I call it for the second time it's calling `test://apps.test.abc.com` may be after getting from cache or cookies. Is there any chance in my native side issue or that is might be fault from 3rd party server side?

Note that for valid redirect_url, web browser works well at the first attempt.

Comment: By any chance is it specific to chrome browser version? Try on latest or recent chrome browser version.